# MySQL : How to filter query using "IN" on Composite Primary Key

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I have a table in MySQL such the primary key is a composite one like this :

```
+--------------+----+------------------------------+
| fk_something | id |            label             |
+--------------+----+------------------------------+
|            1 |  1 | First record of something 1  |
|            2 |  1 | First record of something 2  |
|            2 |  2 | Second record of something 2 |
|            1 |  2 | Second record of something 1 |
|            2 |  3 | Third record of something 2  |
+--------------+----+------------------------------+
```

But now I have a tricky query to do, I want to retrieve for example the 2-1 and 1-2 records using a "IN" filter... How can I do it ?

I tried something like :

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1, 2) AND fk_something IN (2, 1)
```

But it gave me 1-1 and 2-2 records too ...

Comment: Well, you can simply add another filter like `AND id <> fk_something`

Comment: @IVOGELOV in that case yes, you can but this is not a viable solution with hardest queries

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález in fact I'm using a subquery to retrieve some particular ID's... I could explain exactly what I'm trying to achieve BUT i would like to stay simple and ez to understand

Comment: I was wrong, the `(a, b) IN ()` syntax does not require a subquery at all. See your first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the rarely used SQL feature called [row value expressions](https://blog.jooq.org/better-understand-sql-by-adding-optional-parentheses/):

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE (id, fk_something) IN (
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 3)
)
```

Comment: MySQL [supports it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=37c0fc0af9c1b6e018d4e1769aedcb2f). It's awesome, I wasn't aware of this syntax.

Comment: WOW ??? Really ? I'll check this immediatly, thanks for your answer

Comment: Wow this is THE answer :) Thankx it work well